# this.get('content') (inside controller) is undefined after migrating to ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

After migrating from global-namespace-version to ember-cli (0.1.4), my code doesn't work as before. I'm watching the `content` property in my controller to handle the data, fetched in my route. But nothing happens, the `groupedResults` function isn't called.

The data is fetched successfully (Ember Inspector shows all projects), so the `content` property shouldn't be empty.

**Router**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {

  controllerName: 'organization-projects',

  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('project');
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {

    // render all projects
    this.render('organization/projects-list', {
      into: 'application'
    });

    // render toolbar
    this.render('organization/toolbar', {
      into: 'application',
      outlet: 'toolbar'
    });

  }

});
```

**Controller**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  groupedResults: function () {

    console.log(this.get('content'));

  }.property('content.[]')

});
```

Are there some breaking changes that I've missed?

Comment: Yes I'm sure thats Javascript... have a look at Ember/Ember-CLI...

Answer (score 0):

Got it: changed `controllerName: 'organization-projects'` to `controllerName: 'organization.projects'`.

But I wonder why this worked in my old global-namespace-version.